# Ubuntu 18.04 How do I specify jar files for a java program?

Tags: ubuntu, java

I have a java application I copied over from Windows to Ubuntu 18.04. The two important directories are ./bin and ./lib. In ./bin the tree is:

```
bin
└── com
    ├── google
    │   └── protobuf
    ├── program
    │   └── d1
    │       ├── d1a
    │       ├── d1b
    │       ├── d1c
    │       ├── d1d
    │       ├── d1e
    │       └── d1f
    └── mycompany
        ├── d1
        │   └── d1a
        └── myapp
```

The Main.class file exists in ./bin/com/program/d1 (./bin/com/program/d1/Main.class) and there is a set of needed jar files in a ./lib folder.

When I use the following command I get Error: Could not find or load main class bin.com.program.d1.Main and I cannot figure out why. The command is:

```
java -cp ./bin:./lib bin.com.program.d1.Main
```

I have tried ./lib/* and lib and lib/* etc.
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

TIA,
Doug

Answer (score 1):

The package name doesn’t include `bin`, and you need to list the JARs on the classpath:

```sh
CLASSPATH=bin
for jar in lib/*.jar; do CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$jar"; done
export CLASSPATH
java com.program.d1.Main
```

Comment: thank you very much as this was a great suggestion. Unfortunately it still gives me the same error. When I compile this mess that works fine, no complaints. I used

javac -target 1.8 -source 1.8 -cp "lib/*:" -sourcepath src/ -d bin src/com/program/d1/*,java src/com/google/protobuf/*.java src/com/mycompany/di/d1a/*.java src/com/myapp/*.java

Comment: You get the “Error: Could not find or load main class bin.com.program.d1.Main” error again? That one exactly?

Comment: Yes, that one exactly!

Comment: OK, that means you’re not running the `java` command in my answer. You need to drop the `bin.` part of the package name.

Comment: You were correct, I screwed up the command. It tries to start now. The other issues are on my side. Thank you!